# How to round percentage to 2 decimal places in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, rounding

My code produces this graph:

[image]

Code:

```
ggplot(areas, aes(x = RETAILER, y = Difference), label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(areas$Difference, digits = 2))) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = RETAILER), colour = "black") +
scale_y_continuous("Percentage", labels = percent_format()) +
geom_text(aes(label = paste(Difference * 100, "%"),
              vjust = ifelse(Difference >= 0, -1.5, 1.5))) +
theme_classic()
```

I have found code to allow the data labels to be positioned correctly above or below each bar, but I cannot seem to get the values to round to 2 decimal places.

I have tried `round(areas, 2)` and `sprintf("%0.2f")` among other things, but nothing I try seems to work and I'm sure that I'm missing something simple.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

With Roland's "encouragement", I have now managed to *almost* resolve this; the problem now is that I have now lost the percentage signs:

[image]

How do I get them back?

Updated code:

```
ggplot(areas, aes(x = RETAILER, y = Difference)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = RETAILER), colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous("Percentage", labels = percent_format()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%0.2f", areas$Difference * 100, "%"),
                vjust = ifelse(Difference >= 0, -1.5, 1.5))) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: `paste0(round(Difference, 4) * 100, "%")`?

Comment: You define the labels there: `geom_text(aes(label = paste(Difference * 100, "%")`. No rounding there at all.

Comment: @Roland How do I round the values to 2 decimal places?

Comment: You know that. You are only doing it at the wrong place.

Comment: @Roland I see you drive a hard bargain(!)  I have now figured it out, however the percentage symbols have now disappeared - are you able to assist with this?

Comment: `sprintf("%0.2f %%",  Difference * 100)`. Skip the `areas$` if you don't want surprising behavior from ggplot2.

Answer (score 7):

Recent versions of `ggplot2/scales` packages offer arguments to the `scales::percent` function, for instance to round percentages to integers:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1L))
```

This is roughly equivalent to `round(x, 0L)`: Note the `1` instead of `0`.

Or for two digits:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 3L))
```

There is a near-duplicate question. Check Henrik's answer here: [How to prevent scales::percent from adding decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072282/how-to-prevent-scalespercent-from-adding-decimal)

Answer (score 5):

`geom_text(label=percent(Difference,.11))`

Comment: That works. For completeness, I'd probably name the argument just to be safe. i.e., `percent(Difference, accuracy = .11)`

Answer (score 2):

```
aes(label=paste(round(Difference*100,digits= 2),"%",sep=""))
```

Comment: instead of paste(sep=""), you could also use just `paste0`

Answer (score 0):

I use the `percent`function from `formattable` within `geom_text`.
So in your case I would do like so:

```
geom_text(aes(label = formattable::percent(Difference)),
          vjust = ifelse(Difference >= 0, -1.5, 1.5))
```

you can define `digits` within `percent`, but the default is 2, which is what you're looking for. The % symbols remains, like you desire. Plus, you can do stuff with it as it is still `numeric` underneath and not `character` like other solutions out there.