# How to prevent scales::percent from adding decimal

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

This started happening a few days ago, that `scales::percent` would add a decimal place in its labels, and I can't seem to disable this decimal to display integer values on y-axis. [image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = prop)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, but I have used `scales::percent_format` and its `accuracy` argument ("Number to round to") in similar settings.

```
mtcars %>% 
    count(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = prop)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 5L))
```

[image]

---

I think the behaviour of `percent` was changed in `scales 1.0.0`. See [NEWS](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/blob/master/NEWS.md) and updates in code [here](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/commit/4122d63b596926a7c4a98236c67cb4f6d7463690#diff-c6a5818f78b5f4a6559f070399ee5335R202).

Answer (score 20):

Just an update, `scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1L)` will round to the whole number,  `scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.1L)` will round to the first decimal and so on.